# How to run a method with reserved DateTime in Asp.Net Core?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

how can i run a method in asp.net core with a reserved DateTime?

for example i need to send an sms at 2pm to user 1 and send another sms at 3pm to user 2.

by the way i dont want to use a Job method that runs a method every 10 minutes for example.

how could i reserve the run time of a method in advance in a better way?

Comment: May be this answer your question. https://www.blog.jamesmichaelhickey.com/NET-Core-Worker-Services-Background-Job-Scheduler-With-Coravel/#:~:text=One%20of%20those%20features%20is,run%20your%20scheduled%20background%20jobs!

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing to do with ASP.NET Core specifically.
For that kind of task consider using cron jobs in Linux or Task Scheduler in Windows.